# Browser plugin to recognize a custom image-format

Tags: firefox-addon, google-chrome-extension, browser-plugin, browser-extension

I have images that are in a custom file-format (basically containing RAW data)
and and I want to have them viewable in a browser (without converting them to
standard formats such as jpg/png).

Is it possible to write a browser plugin  that would read my-custom-format
and display the images in the browser (like say a PDF reader) ?

I can do this using Flash, but I am trying to see if I can avoid having to 
download the Flash SWF to display the image.

Can a browser plugin/extension get binary data from the web, process it and
render it on a specific area on the browser screen ? Which browsers would it
be possible on and which ones would it not be ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download binary file with `XMLHttpRequest` and display in on `<canvas>` element, where you have full control over each pixel.

Now if you mean you want the browser to natively recognize your custom image format this could be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this in all browsers. ActiveX for IE, and NPAPI for everything else.